# 'HMODULE GetModuleHandleW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++

I'm still rather new to C++ but I've ran into a problem I can't solve, this is my error message:

> 'HMODULE GetModuleHandleW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

And this the line that is throwing the error:

```
        ModuleHandle = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(moduleName.c_str());
```

Comment: You have sent an invalid value

Comment: use `std::wstring moduleName = L"foo";`

Comment: You are expecting your program to be ASCII but the project settings are UNICODE.  If you change the project to not use UNICODE then what you wrote will work.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `char *` to something that needs a `wchar_t *`. You'll have to either convert your stringtype to wchar_t *, for example using the MultiByteToWideChar function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or you can use the non-wide version of GetModuleHandle by calling GetModuleHandleA() instead of GetModuleHandleW().